# Change of font not working for the website

Tags: c#, asp.net, fonts

I have an asp.net website, in which I need to change the textbox font depending upon    the language selected by the user.There are 2 radio buttons for 2 different languages English and Hindi.When the user selects one of these languages,the textbox font is changed through the following piece of code:

```
if(rbEnglish.Checked==true)
{
    TextBox1.Font.Name="Times New Roman";
}
else if(rbHindi.Checked==true)
{
    TextBox1.Font.Name="Shivaji05";
}
```

This works on the local computer but when the website is hosted,the Hindi font does not appear.What should be done to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is strange; I think you made a simple mistake. Did you check your website with some developers tools like FireBug(in firefox), be sure that your text box gets your font style; there may be a css style in your host that overrides your internal style with somthing like "!important". Another possibility, Are you sure that you are visiting it on a client that has your Hindi font? Are you updating your text box with asp:UpdatePanel? does it work fine for other activities?

Comment: You are right that the client might not have the Hindi font but I would like to have my website working on all systems whether the Hindi font exists or not.

Comment: @TVicky, if so, you should embed your font in your website. The advantage of this method is you can freely use your font and the disadvantage of this method is that client will download the embedded font in its request (like css, js and so on), so you may have heavier page; however embedded font is cache-able.